# how to set pytesseract to solve captcha alphanumeric and 5 length

Tags: opencv, tesseract, python-3.8, python-tesseract

Hi everybody I'm using pytesseract and tesseract-ocr-w32-setup-v5.0.0-alpha and pytesseract in python 3.8, I did this code to try to recognize 5 alphanumeric characters:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(r'imagenes/captcha.JPG', lang='spa', config='psm 10')
if len(text)>5:
    text = text[0:5]
print(text)
```

The problem is that it didn't work correctly. In the case of this image

[image: the captcha image]

It returns swQgy. I read about some settings: for example, they can be disabled by setting both of the configuration variables load_system_dawg and load_freq_dawg to false in case to avoid dictionary, but I don't know how to do this. In addition, I'm not sure if I can say the lenght of the captcha and avoiding confusion with lines distractions. Thanks in advance.

[image: This is the result]

**UPDATE:**

I have an update, I could solve the confusion pre procesing the image with cv2. Now my problem is with the letter z, it confuses with the number 2. This is my new code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
image = cv2.imread('captcha.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 3)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='spa', config='--oem 1 --psm 6')
if len(text)>5:
    text = text[0:5]
print(text)
```

Is possible to tune much better? I'm new in pytesseract. This is my new captcha and the result:

[image: the new captcha]

[image]